# 360° slerp horizontal rotation camera with the slider

Tags: 3d, rotation, slider, 360-degrees

I'm trying to create a script that allows me to rotate the camera, with a Slerp effect, in a range from 0 ° -360 ° (y-axis) through a horizontal slider. The camera only rotates along an axis (I'm in the middle of a room and I have to turn around using a horizontal slider)

I made two scripts:
The first to be applied to a reference cube to obtain the rotation and the second to be applied to the chamber to obtain the Slerp effect, while following the rotation of the cube.

360 ° cube rotation script:

```
    public float speed;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public GameObject ObjectToRotate;

    public void SliderChanged(float speed)
    {
        ObjectToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (speed*offset);
}
```

Script for camera rotation with Slerp effect:

```
    public Transform target;
    public float Speed = 0.1F;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, target.rotation, Speed);     
    }
}
```

It works but with some problems: 
if I run too fast with the slider from the left (0 °) to the right (359 °), the Slerp rotation does not continue correctly but seems to rotate only 1 °, as if it were back.

How can I solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Slerp` will always take the shortest path between orientations, so if you start at `0` and want to end at `359` then you won't get nice rotation through all those values, but you'll get what you see already.

Here's my idea how to solve it:

1. Don't use `Transform` to pass data from UI slider to object. Use just a `float` with angle value. Get it from UI and pass it to the object as a target rotation.
2. The object you want to rotate stores its last rotation value as float. When you set it the new target it does interpolation of this float, per frame. Let's say your rotation was `0`, now you set the target to `359`, so we're rotating from `0` in positive direction. If speed per frame is `10 deg` then you end up with rotation `10` and store it as your last rotation.
3. If the rotation has changed then you compute the **new** quaternion using your angle value (10).

This way you have your interpolation done in linear space, where `0-359` range behaves as you expected. Then, after the interpolation you introduce Quaternions to use this value as rotational data.

BTW: With this trick you can also use bigger range, like 0-720 to be able to do two or more revolutions. You can't do the same using Quaternions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Despite the impediments I have with the code, I will do some tests.

Comment: I tried to write the script but I can not solve it. The rotation moves only by the value assigned in the script (10). Can someone help me?

public GameObject ObjectToRotate;
    float valueAngle=10f;
    Quaternion rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis(10f,Vector3.up);


    public void SliderChanged(float speed)
    {
        ObjectToRotate.transform.rotation = rot;
    }

}